# Positional indexing with NA values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to index the dataframe from positional index, but I got NA values in previous operation and I wanna preserve it. How could I achieve this?

df1

```
NaN
1
NaN
NaN
NaN
6
```

df2

```
0 10
1 15
2 13
3 15
4 16
5 17
6 17
7 18
8 10
```

df3

```
0 15
1 17
```

The output I want

```
NaN
15
NaN
NaN
NaN
17

df2.iloc(df1)

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

.iloc method in this case drive to a unbound error, I think .iloc is not available here. df3 is another output generated by .loc, but I don't know how to add NaN between them. If you can achieve output by using df1 and df3 is also ok

Comment: the question is unclear, you should provide the dataframe constructors and explicit which `loc`/`iloc` commands you have run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df1` and `df2` has same index values use for replace non missing values by values from another DataFrame [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
df1 = df2.mask(df1.isna())
print (df1)
    col
0   NaN
1  15.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5  17.0
```